# Twitter Bootstrap Popover incorrectly positioned in Chrome/Webkit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Using bootstrap 2.1 I have a popover inside a modal window. The popover is triggered when the user clicks on the help icon. In Firefox, it is positioned correctly:
http://i49.tinypic.com/30ry3at.png

but in Chrome, it appears positioned aligned with the left edge of the modal:
http://i48.tinypic.com/25us6dw.png

How can I make it appear correctly? I'm tearing my hair out over here...

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look.